# Where does this proof of the Leibniz integral rule go wrong?

Tags: calculus

$\renewcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}$
Define
$$I(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, t)\,\diff t.$$
We wish to show that
$$\frac{\diff I}{\diff x} = f(x, b(x))\frac{\diff b}{\diff x}-f(x, a(x))\frac{\diff a}{\diff x}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\diff t.$$
I am familiar with the proof involving $\frac{1}{h}(I(x+h)-I(x))$, but decided to try an alternative method.

---

Let $F(x, t)$ be a function such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = f$. The specific choice isn't important because the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus works with any antiderivative. Now
$$I(x) = F(x, b(x))-F(x, a(x))$$
and by chain rule, the derivative is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\diff I}{\diff x} &= \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\diff b}{\diff x}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\frac{\diff a}{\diff x}\right)\\
&= \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}(x, b(x))\frac{\diff b}{\diff x}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}(x, a(x))\frac{\diff a}{\diff x}\\
&= f(x, b(x))\frac{\diff b}{\diff x}-f(x, a(x))\frac{\diff a}{\diff x}.
\end{align*}

---

Now clearly something has gone wrong because an entire term is missing compared to what we're trying to prove. So the question is where is the error, and is the proof salvageable after correcting it? Or is there a good reason no one uses this method?

Comment: If you don't omit all the arguments then you'll note that (for example) the two $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ terms do *not* cancel.

Comment: @MartinR Oh you're right, I've used $F$ to refer to two different functions. I did have a feeling the mistake was something obvious.

Comment: The specific choice of the antiderivative does matter as we are dealing with functions in two variables. You can take $$F(x,t)=\int\limits_{t_0}^t f(x,s)\,ds$$ The two  terms $\partial F/\partial x$ showing up in your reasoning are evaluated at different points.You should not write $\partial F/\partial b$ or  $\partial F/\partial a$ but $\partial F/\partial t$ in both cases.